# Get photo from database and show it in list view

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, kotlin

I'm working on a Note App in android studio with Kotlin. The app has a Main Activity with a list view and a floating action button and an Add Note Activity with a title edit text, note edit text, an insert picture button, a save button and an image view.

When you touch the floating button it gets you to the App Note Activity. There, you can write your note, insert your picture and see it in the image view and finally save them in the SQLite database. When you go back to Main Activity it supposed to show the title with its picture in the list view. 
The last part is my problem! Instead of creating list view, the app crashes out.

**Android Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="soroush.l.noteproject">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddNoteActivity"></activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

**Add Note Activity:**

```
class AddNoteActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val GALLERY = 1
private val CAMERA = 2
var path = myPath()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_note)

    buttonAddPic.setOnClickListener {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            val array = Array<String>(1) { Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, array, 1)
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            val array = Array<String>(1) { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, array, 1)
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            val array = Array<String>(1) { Manifest.permission.CAMERA }
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, array, 1)
        } else
            showPictureDialog()

    }

    buttonSave.setOnClickListener {
        var dbManager = DBManager(this)

        var values = ContentValues()
        values.put("Title",editTextTitle.text.toString())
        values.put("Note", editTextNote.text.toString())

        val fis = FileInputStream(path.picPath)
        val image = ByteArray(fis.available())
        fis.read(image)

        values.put("Pic", image)

        val ID = dbManager.insert(values)

        fis.close()

        if (ID > 0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Note was saved!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        finish()

    }
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (grantResults.size > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            showPictureDialog()
        }
    }
}

private fun showPictureDialog() {
    val pictureDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    pictureDialog.setTitle("")
    val pictureDialogItems = arrayOf("Select photo from gallery", "Take photo with camera")
    pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems
    ) { dialog, which ->
        when (which) {
            0 -> choosePhotoFromGallary()
            1 -> takePhotoFromCamera()
        }
    }
    pictureDialog.show()
}

fun choosePhotoFromGallary() {
    val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)

    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY)
}

private fun takePhotoFromCamera() {
    val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA)
}

public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode:Int, resultCode:Int, data: Intent?) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == GALLERY)
    {
        if (data != null)
        {
            val contentURI = data!!.data
            try
            {
                val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver, contentURI)
                val path = saveImage(bitmap)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Photo was saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                imageViewShowPic!!.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

            }
            catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }

    }
    else if (requestCode == CAMERA)
    {
        val thumbnail = data!!.extras!!.get("data") as Bitmap
        imageViewShowPic!!.setImageBitmap(thumbnail)
        saveImage(thumbnail)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Photo was saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

fun saveImage(myBitmap: Bitmap):String {
    val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes)
    val wallpaperDirectory = File(
            (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()).toString() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY)

    Log.d("fee",wallpaperDirectory.toString())
    if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists())
    {

        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs()
    }

    try
    {
        Log.d("heel",wallpaperDirectory.toString())
        val f = File(wallpaperDirectory, ((Calendar.getInstance()
                .getTimeInMillis()).toString() + ".jpg"))
        f.createNewFile()
        val fo = FileOutputStream(f)
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray())
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                arrayOf(f.getPath()),
                arrayOf("image/jpeg"), null)
        fo.close()
        Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath())

        path.picPath=f.absolutePath

        return f.getAbsolutePath()

    }
    catch (e1: IOException) {
        e1.printStackTrace()
    }

    return ""
}

companion object {
    private val IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/demonuts"
}}
```

**Class myPath:**

```
class myPath {
var picPath:String? = null}
```

**SQLite Database:**

```
class DBManager {

val dbName = "NotesDB"
val dbTable = "tblNotes"
val colID = "ID"
val colTitle = "Title"
val colNote = "Note"
val colPic = "Pic"
val dbVersion = 1

val sqlCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + dbTable + " " +
        "(" + colID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + colTitle + " TEXT, " + colNote + " TEXT, " + colPic + " BLOB);"

var sqlDB: SQLiteDatabase? = null

constructor(context: Context)
{
    val db = DatabaseHelper(context)
    sqlDB = db.writableDatabase
}

inner class DatabaseHelper : SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    var context: Context? = null

    constructor(context: Context): super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion)
    {
        this.context = context
    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {

        db!!.execSQL(sqlCreateTable)

    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {

        db!!.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + dbTable)

    }

}

fun insert (values: ContentValues) : Long
{
    val ID = sqlDB!!.insert(dbTable,"",values)
    return ID
}

fun RunQuery(columns:Array<String>, selection: String, selectionArgs:Array<String>, sortOrder: String): Cursor
{
    val qb = SQLiteQueryBuilder()
    qb.tables = dbTable
    val cursor = qb.query(sqlDB, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder)
    return cursor
}}
```

**Main Activity:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var listOfNotes = ArrayList<Note>()

override fun onResume() {
    LoadData("%")
    super.onResume()
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    LoadData("%")

    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
        var intent = Intent(this,AddNoteActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

}

fun LoadData(title:String)
{
    var dbManager = DBManager(this)

    val columns = arrayOf("ID", "Title", "Note", "Pic")
    val selectionArgs = arrayOf(title)

    val cursor = dbManager.RunQuery(columns,"Title like ?", selectionArgs,"Title")

    listOfNotes.clear()

    if (cursor.moveToFirst() == true)
    {
        do
        {
            val ID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"))
            val Title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Title"))
            val Note = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Note"))
            val Pic = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("Pic"))
            val BMP = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Pic,cursor.getColumnIndex("Pic"),Pic!!.size)

            listOfNotes.add(Note(ID,Title,Note,BMP))

        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
    }


    var noteAdapter = NoteAdapter(this, listOfNotes)
    listViewNotes.adapter = noteAdapter

}

inner class NoteAdapter : BaseAdapter {

    var notesList = ArrayList<Note>()
    var context: Context? = null

    constructor(context: Context, notesList:ArrayList<Note>){
        this.notesList=notesList
        this.context = context
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {

        var view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_pattern,null)
        var note = notesList[position]

        view.textViewTitle.text = note.Title
        view.imageViewPic.setImageBitmap(note.BMP)

        return view
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return notesList[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return notesList.size
    }
}}
```

**Class Note:**

```
class Note {

var ID:Int? = null
var Title:String? = null
var Note:String? = null
var BMP:Bitmap? = null

constructor(id:Int,title:String,note:String,bmp:Bitmap)
{
    ID = id
    Title = title
    Note = note
    BMP = bmp
}}
```

*layout add note*

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AddNoteActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNote"
        android:layout_width="311dp"
        android:layout_height="141dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Your Note ..."
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.508"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAddPic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Add Picture"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextNote"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewShowPic"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.913" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewShowPic"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="149dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Save"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextNote"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTitle"
        android:layout_width="309dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Title"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageViewShowPic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

*layout main:*

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewNotes"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

*layout list_view_pattern:*

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="23sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPic"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            tools:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you see "Error" or "Note was saved!" toast?

Comment: @mTak No I don't

Comment: So maybe nothing is saved in the db. Can you post your logcat?

Comment: @mTak https://www.uplooder.net/img/image/48/b39c413c445583203c8d009e68cf29bc/Logcat.PNG

Comment: Try changing `val BMP = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Pic,cursor.getColumnIndex("Pic"),Pic!!.size)` to `val BMP = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Pic,0,Pic!!.size)`

Comment: @mTak OMG it worked! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'll write answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the log it shows that the error is due to an out of bounds array and that the latest call from your code was from LoadData. The only array in LoadData is the byte array which is converted to a bitmap.

The decode/convert takes theree parameters a byte array, an offset and the length. It converts the byte array, starting at the offset for the number of bytes given as the last parameter. So say you had a 100 byte array and the column index was 1 then you are saying convert bytes 1-100 byte 100 is out of bounds (you only have 0 - 99).

As such you just need to code 0 as the offset. So change :-

```
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Pic,cursor.getColumnIndex("Pic"),Pic!!.size)
```

to

```
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Pic,0,Pic!!.size)
```